# Can Chocolatey recognize a manual nodejs installation?

Tags: node.js, npm, updates, chocolatey

Running command `node -v` gives the following value: `v0.10.33`. I know that Node.js currently is at version 0.12. Nevertheless, when running a `choco update nodejs`, the prompt says "Nothing to update". The same occurs with npm after a "choco update npm".

I have installed Node.js from the install package on their website nodejs.org.
A time after that I have also installed Chocolatey and have come to use the tool every now and then for package installations.

Is it possible to have Chocolatey recognize the existing Node.js installation and pick a choco update from there?

I would like to also be able to pick up the npm update from Chocolatey the same way as well.

---

I do not have the latest Chocolatey.

```
> choco list --local-only nodejs 
Opción desconocida: '--local-only' 

nodejs.commandline 0.12.2 
npm 1.4.9.20150213 
EthanBrown.DevTools.Web 0.3.1 
ghost 0.5.5.1 
io.js 1.7.1 
livestreamer-twitch-gui 0.7.1 
nodejs 0.12.2 
nodejs.install 0.12.2 
node-webkit-0.9.2 0.9.2 
node-webkit 0.6.2 
Brackets.Theseus 0.2.8 
Yeoman 1.1.2
```

---

After upgrading Chocolatey to v0.9.9.4

```
> choco list --local-only
Chocolatey v0.9.9.4 [nl] 0 packages installed.
```

I updated Node.js using npm.

```
> node -v
v0.12.2
```

However, after reinstalling Node.js at version 0.10.33,

```
> choco install nodejs -version 0.10.33
```

I cannot use `npm`:

> Cannot find file at 'npm.cmd' (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\npm\tools\npm.cmd). This usually indicates a missing or moved file.

I'll leave it for now until I troubleshoot.

Answer (score 5):

Another option, assuming that you already have Node.js installed via the MSI would be to run:

`choco install nodejs -version 0.12.2 -y -n`

The -n parameter, as documented here:

https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CommandsInstall#options-and-switches

Skips the PowerShell script associated with the Chocolatey package. This essentially adds the package version into the Chocolatey repository, but it doesn't run the associated installation script.

This is what I "think" you are after.

**NOTE:** Not all packages have chocolateyinstall.ps1 files, and instead rely on the default installation behaviour of Chocolatey, i.e. creating shims for contained EXE files, etc. The skippowershell flag will not, to the best of my knowledge, stop this from happening.

Comment: Hello, I have already upgraded to latest version. After upgrading my nodejs to v.0.12.2, I've used the command provided to install the previous version of nodejs (0.10.33). Now I need to troubleshoot why npm is not being recognized and being referred to chocolatey installation path. (See my 3rd comment on http://stackoverflow.com/a/29704118/1960071 within this thread). Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to have 2 different node versions installed at once on your machine, or simply that you are trying to install an older version, instead of the newer one?

Comment: My aim was to have one version of nodejs installed, be it older or newer. But now that you mentioned, is it possible to install two or more nodejs versions through chocolatey?

Comment: In Chocolatey < 0.9.8.33, the answer out of the box was yes.  In Chocolatey > 0.9.9.0 that changed somewhat.  It is still possible, but there is an additional flag on installation to flag, documented here: choco install crashplan -version 3.7.1 (-sxs) which allows this to happen.  Without this flag in place, I think you might be seeing "weird" stuff happen with the generated shims etc, overwriting what is already in place, but that is just a guess.

Comment: What I found out after installing a new nodejs through chocolatey -on top of the existing installation- is that the new npm cmd had its env path copied above the existing installation's. I uninstalled the choco npm after, but the env path from such install was preserved but pointing to the deleted installation hosted by chocolatey. I looked into PATH env variable, but there was no trace of the culprit string that was left in system. Had to install and uninstall again, then the left out string was removed. That was weird.

Answer (score 1):

Chocolatey cannot currently detect and incorporate already installed applications into its own library. Now, if you installed the Node.js MSI manually and then used Chocolatey to install the same or newer version, things might just work. The MSI system, while arcane, is pretty robust and most newer MSIs will subsume older ones.

Can you run the Chocolatey command to show us exactly which Node.js you have installed?

```
PS> choco list --local-only nodejs
Chocolatey v0.9.9.2
nodejs 0.10.33
nodejs.install 0.10.33
2 packages installed.
```

I have the same version installed. I just ran an update. I snipped the logs, but you can see that it updates.

```
PS> choco upgrade nodejs
Chocolatey v0.9.9.2

nodejs.install v0.12.2
nodejs v0.12.2

Chocolatey upgraded 2/2 package(s). 0 package(s) failed.
```

And Node.js is up-to-date.

```
PS> node -v
v0.12.2
```

And the application in the *Programs and Features* applet of the Control Panel is also updated. So, the Node.js MSI does the right thing here.

[image]

I think we need to see some more literal command output from your system to be sure you have all the right versions installed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I noticed you used "choco upgrade" instead of "choco update".
The command "choco list --local-only nodejs" produces the following output:
E:\> choco list --local-only nodejs
Opción desconocida: '--local-only'
nodejs.commandline 0.12.2
npm 1.4.9.20150213
EthanBrown.DevTools.Web 0.3.1
ghost 0.5.5.1
io.js 1.7.1
livestreamer-twitch-gui 0.7.1
nodejs 0.12.2
nodejs.install 0.12.2
node-webkit-0.9.2 0.9.2
node-webkit 0.6.2
Brackets.Theseus 0.2.8
Yeoman 1.1.2

Haven´t noticed that maybe I have chocolatey version not updated yet.

Comment: Oh, line formatting was not applied to previous answer.

Comment: After having upgraded chocolatey to v. 0.9.9.4, the command "choco list --local-only" returns the following: "Chocolatey v0.9.9.4 [nl] 0 packages installed." However, if I run "node -v" it displays the version 0.12.2, which is correct, since I had updated nodejs using npm's package nuw. 
However, after reinstalling nodejs at v.0.10.33 using "choco install nodejs -version 0.10.33" now cannot use npm, which throws the error "Cannot find file at 'npm.cmd' (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\npm\tools\npm.cmd). This usually indicates a missing or moved file." I'll leave it for now until I troubleshoot.

Comment: Chocolatey ***can*** take over existing installations, but there is a caveat on that - installer packages it takes over on an upgrade. If it came onto the system in a different way, it may not be able to take over an existing install. As of the current date, there is now `choco sync` in Chocolatey for Business that brings everything already installed in Programs and Features under Chocolatey management very quickly. https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-synchronize#sync-command

Comment: @ferventcoder this answer is 2 years old, of course Chocolatey can do everything now! 

Comment: I saw that. StackExchange does not exist on time though, so out of date answers should get updated from time to time. :)

Comment: @ferventcoder would it make sense to post the latest answer? Or update this one? So it's not lost in comments.